# Monitoring interfaces on VyOS then SSH output to another machine (Security Onion)

Tags: security, ssh, vyos

I am trying to figure out the best way I can monitor interfaces on a VyOS interface from a Security Onion instance using Squil (Snort alerts etc).  I am thinking SSH to VyOS to activate monitor interfaces traffic and outputting to file on SecOnion, but this may be too verbose and fill up space quick. Is there an alternative you think?

Regards

Rob